# How to get deleted file information along with kernel version?

Tags: git, linux-kernel

In kernel version **linux-4.4.y** found that **rtmutex-tester.c** file is missing from **kernel/locking** directory. This file was part of **linux-4.1.y** kernel version. I just want to know in which kernel version **rtmutex-tester.c** is removed? I tried with **git log** but didn't get any information.

Is there any git command available to get the deleted file information with kernel version?

Comment: "I tried with git log but didn't get any information." please describe more, what went wrong? I'd think that `git log -- kernel/locking/rtmutex-tester.c` as first commit should show you the one where it was removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git log --name-status -- kernel/locking/rtmutex-tester.c` shows the following output:

```
commit 1b0b7c1762679a2f8bc359da95649249dfcf4195
Author: Davidlohr Bueso <dave@stgolabs.net>
Date:   Wed Jul 1 13:29:48 2015 -0700

rtmutex: Delete scriptable tester

No one uses this anymore, and this is not the first time the
idea of replacing it with a (now possible) userspace side.
Lock stealing logic was removed long ago in when the lock
was granted to the highest prio.

...

D       kernel/locking/rtmutex-tester.c
```

The **D** indicates deletion when `--name-status` is used.
When using `git log --name-status tags/v4.2  -- kernel/locking/rtmutex-tester.c` the commit is missing; for 4.3 it is available. In conclusion: It was deleted with Kernel 4.3.